# How to authorize with roles in .Net core with ForgeRock

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

Net core application. I am using forgerock jwt authentication. I am trying to implement  authorization using authorization filter. Below is my code for authorization filter

```
public class JwTFilter : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IAuthService _authService;

        public JwTFilter(IAuthService authHandler)
        {
            this._authService = authHandler;
        }
        async Task IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var jwt = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authorizationHeader);
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorizationHeader))
            {
            }

            AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authorizationHeader);

            if (!authHeader.Scheme.Equals("Bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader.Parameter))
            {

            }

            var result = await _authService.ValidateAndBuildUserCalims(authHeader.Parameter);

            stopwatch.Stop(); // Stop the stopwatch

            return;
        }
    }
```

In the above code method _authService.ValidateAndBuildUserCalims(authHeader.Parameter) validates the token. I have below controller

```
 [Authorize(Roles = RolesConstant.Manager)]
        public async Task<DetailDto> GetTestData()
        {
            DetailDto data= new DetailDto();
            return data;
        }
```

I have added filter in program.cs as below

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<JwTFilter>();
});
```

When I pass valid token to the above API with proper roles, my filter validates the token properly but line  [Authorize(Roles = RolesConstant.Manager)] fails with unauthorized. May I know what would be the root cause. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you able to resolve your issue? Do you still have any concern on this? Let me know if you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I pass valid token to the above API with proper roles, my filter
> validates the token properly but line [Authorize(Roles =
> RolesConstant.Manager)] fails with unauthorized. May I know what would
> be the root cause.

Well, based on your shared code snippet and configuration it doesn't seems your cofiguration has any issue but the supportability or case-sensitive fact involved.

However, there might be couple of other issues as well for that unauthorize incident.

First of all, as you may know claims are case-sensitve, make sure that, the token contains the expected role claim and that the role claim matches the RolesConstant.Manager value. You can decode your token claims if those are exactly same with your configuration here in [JWT decoder.](https://jwt.io/)

Another important point is that, by default, the role claim is typically named "role" in the JWT. If it has a different name, you need to specify it explicitly in your [Authorize] attribute and also double check if it's containing the `RolesConstant.Manager` within your token.

Most importantly, gone through the [forgerock](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/idcloud/latest/idm-auth/authorization-and-roles.html#access-json) document if the support the way you are sending your role claims. Because, forgerock usually allows claims with comma sperated value. So make sure, if your confiuration that particular pattern is correct.

Finally check above steps accordingly  and If the problem persists, please share your stacktrace details and `RolesConstant.Manager` details how you are configuring them.